# HTML form only sends part of option value back to Flask

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I'm getting a bad value when I return this option. For example, when i send n = "Arnold, Robert | ID: 1" as an option, it shows up on the web page, but when the user clicks submit, only "Arnold," is sent to my Flask Server. I'm trying to get the ID value out.

Does anyone know how to retrieve the entire option value from the form or another way to get the ID out of the string?

Here's the HTML

```
<h2>Donors</h2>                                       
<form method="POST" action="/display_donor">
  <select name="selected_donor">
    {% for n in donors %}
      <option value={{n}}>{{n}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <br />
  <br><input type="submit" value="View donor"/>
</form>
```

Here's the relevant Flask function

```
@app.route('/display_donor', methods=['POST'])
def display_donor():
  temp_id = request.form['selected_donor']
  print "temp_id"
  print temp_id
  final_id = re.sub('[^0-9]','', temp_id)
  print "final_id"
  print final_id
  display_value = 1

  cursor = g.conn.execute("SELECT name,donor_id FROM donors")
  donors = []
  for result in cursor:
    temp_string = result['name'] + " | ID: " +result['donor_id']
    donors.append(temp_string)
      # can also be accessed using result[0]
  cursor.close()  

  print "this"
  print final_id

  #Returns a specific instance of transaction as specified by user
  cursor = g.conn.execute("SELECT * FROM donors D WHERE D.donor_id='%s'" % final_id)
  values = []
  for result in cursor:
    values.append(result['donor_id'])
    values.append(result['name'])
    values.append(result['donor_type'])
  cursor.close()

  #denote attribute names
  attribute = []
  attribute.append('donor_id')
  attribute.append('name')
  attribute.append('donor_type')

  return render_template("donors.html",attribute=attribute,values=values,donors=donors,display_value=display_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by sending the values separately rather than as a single string. This got me out of all the parsing and allowed me to print out the values like so:

```
<h2>Donors</h2>                                       
<form method="POST" action="/display_donor">
  <select name="selected_donor">
    {% for n in donor_ids %}
      <option value={{n}}>{{ donor_names[loop.index0] }} | ID: {{n}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <br />
  <br><input type="submit" value="View donor"/>
</form>
```